# How opensea fetch data from the blockchain for the website?

Tags: nft

I see that image sources are from seadn.io. I assume it is a opensea service where all changes on the blockchain, regarding the nfts are stored? And opensea website is fetching data from there?

What about offers? Are they on the blockchain, or are they off-chain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what role seadn.io plays but it seems like a play on CDN (content delivery network) and OpenSea = SeaDN.io. SeaDN.io doesn't resolve to anything but it's registered with Cloudflare and owned by OpenSea. The images itself should not be on infrastructure owned by OpenSea or CloudFlare, instead the images are stored on IPFS.

Regarding offers on OpenSea, they are off-chain initially. When a user makes an offer on an NFT, the offer is stored on OpenSea's servers, and the information is not written to the blockchain until the offer is accepted by the NFT owner. Once the NFT owner accepts the offer, a smart contract is executed on the Ethereum blockchain to facilitate the transfer of the NFT and the payment in cryptocurrency. This off-chain approach helps reduce the transaction costs (gas fees) associated with interacting with the Ethereum blockchain, as well as speeds up the offering process.